# c source with headers and include

Tags: c, header, init

in c header file,Why I don't have to include the define of some types I made,I can use it directly in header as long as I include the def in c file ? because that's impossible in c++ I think,for example:

define.h

```
typedef int _int32;
```

object.h

```
_int32 num;

void   init();
```

object.c

```
#include define.h

void init()
{
 num = 12;
}
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question with more pauses and punctuation? I did not understand what what you asked...

Comment: If this is your only code, this definitely won't compile.

Comment: Where are you including object.h? That makes all the difference.

Comment: I mean I didn't include define.h,then I use type _int32 in the object.h directly,then it compiles fine I don't get it.

Comment: @user1051003 please update your code with a complete example of what you are compiling (`gcc -c object.c` should succeed). As Oil pointed out the current example will not compile. And when your example compiles I guarantee somehow define.h was include before object.h which is why it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Either your compiler is wrong, or you are (I bet on the latter). Post your entire code.

My guess is that you either:

- included `object.h` in `define.h`
- included some other file that has a declaration of `num`
- you're not compiling your source code

Anyway, until you post your actual code we can't tell for sure.

EDIT:

If your problem is that you can use  `_int32` without the include, bear in mind that  `_int32` can be a basic type on some platforms. But in your example, you're using `num`, which is impossible.

Comment: omg you found the reason,I did include object.h on some other place.thanks

Answer (score -1):

You never include object.h, otherwise that would work. Typically, however, `_int32 num` would still be in the .c file.

Comment: His question is why it works without including "object.h".

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what your problem exactly is, but you can learn a lot by letting the compiler generate preprocessed output and looking at it.